# Get data from h2 database via spring-boot [JAVA]

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I'm in the process of learning java spring. Now I am trying to retrieve data from the database. I rely on this tutorial https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-and-spring-jdbc-with-h2

When I try to get data from the database via ID I get this error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:542)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:782)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:763)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at com.exam.kino.KinoApplication.main(KinoApplication.java:25)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.exam.kino.database.Seans]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.exam.kino.database.Seans.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:129)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper.mapRow(BeanPropertyRowMapper.java:285)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:678)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:616)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:699)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:782)
    at com.exam.kino.repository.SeansRepository.findById(SeansRepository.java:26)
    at com.exam.kino.repository.SeansRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a208ec27.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.exam.kino.repository.SeansRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b326407c.findById(<generated>)
    at com.exam.kino.KinoApplication.run(KinoApplication.java:31)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.exam.kino.database.Seans.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:122)
    ... 31 more
```

This is my database (schema.sql and import.sql):

```
create table seans
(
   id integer not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
   title varchar(255) not null,
   datetime TIMESTAMP not null,
   primary key(id)
);
INSERT INTO seans (id, title, DATETIME) VALUES (1,'Captain America',parsedatetime('30-06-2016 08:00', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'));
INSERT INTO seans (id, title, DATETIME) VALUES (2,'Antman',parsedatetime('30-06-2016 10:00', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'));
INSERT INTO seans (id, title, DATETIME) VALUES (3,'Ironman',parsedatetime('30-06-2016 12:00', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm'));
```

Seans class (I used Lombok and annotation @Data here):

```
package com.exam.kino.database;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Table(name="seans")
@Entity
public class Seans {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "datetime")
    private Date datetime;

    public Seans(int id, String title, Date datetime) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.datetime = datetime;
    }
}
```

My repository class:

```
package com.exam.kino.repository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.exam.kino.database.Seans;

import antlr.collections.List;

@Repository
public class SeansRepository
{
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    public Seans findById(long id) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from seans where id=? ", new Object[] {
                id
        },new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Seans>(Seans.class));
    }
}
```

And last my main class with method call:

```
package com.exam.kino;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.exam.kino.repository.SeansRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class KinoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    SeansRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KinoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Seans id 1 - > {}", repository.findById(1));
    }
}
```

Somebody had this type of error and know how repair this?

Comment: The message tells you what the problem is: Failed to instantiate [com.exam.kino.database.Seans]: No default constructor found. JPA entities must have a no-argument constructor.

Comment: Note however that you're using JPA annotations, but using a repository that uses JDBC, and not JPA. That doesn't make much sense. But in any case,  BeanPropertyRowMapper also needs a no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the no-arg-constructor created by Lombok by adding one more annotation:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="seans")
@Entity
public class Seans {
  // ...
}
```

}

and **do not** declare your own constructor; `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor` (which is implicit by using `@Data`) will only work if you do not have custom constructors.

Answer (score 1):

From your error logs,

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.exam.kino.database.Seans.<init>()
```

It is looking for a default constructor. Try defining a default constructor in Seans class.

---

**Recommendation for getting data with spring boot**

You can extend CRUDRepository or JPARepository to your Repository class to fetch data. Repository will construct the table and query itself.

You can follow this guide
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above:

1. More attentively read stack trace messages - there you can find information about your error.
2. You need to read JPA specification (https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_2-mrel-eval-spec/index.html), here you will find much information.

It is your case:
"The entity class must have a no-arg constructor. The entity class may have other constructors as well. The no-arg constructor must be public or protected"